# What is the default Swift version for auto suggestion on Xcode Version 9.0 beta?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

What is the default Swift version for auto suggestion on Xcode version 9.0 beta?

Is it Swift 3 or Swift 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for more reference you can get the document from [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Compatibility.html)

> You can use Xcode 9 to build targets that are written in either Swift 4 or Swift 3.
>
> **When the Swift 4 compiler is working with Swift 3 code**, it identifies its language **version as 3.2**. As a result, you can use conditional compilation blocks like **#if swift(>=3.2)** to write code that’s compatible with multiple versions of the Swift compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is **Swift 4**. Apple always encourages to use the latest language and its features.

Comment: Is there any property in XCode that we can check that says which version it is auto suggesting by default?

Comment: If you are changing the [development language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118912/use-legacy-swift-language-version-xcode-8-2), auto suggestions will change with it.