# Failed CryptoSwift Lib installation for Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to use AES encryption/decryption using CryptoSwift library.
I used a library using pod. following pod I used.
`pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => "master"`
After installing pod in a project when I compiled the project it's give number of errors.
[image]

Comment: can you please try only with pod 'CryptoSwift'

Comment: yes i also tried but did not get any success

Comment: what is swift version?

Comment: i used swift 4.0 and xcode9.2

Comment: It should work, as it is working over here

Comment: Can you please provide me a demo project link ?
It would be great help for me and thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have demo, I have created one. can you please share your code?

Comment: I did not added any code.just install the pod and build a project that time i got a number of errors.

Comment: send me that code, I will resolve it

Comment: here is link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/osxqv1414apcyjy/CryptoSwiftDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: give me few mins plz

Comment: let me know once you download so I can remove from my dropbox

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security such as timing and power attacks.

Comment: @zaph As per my project requirement i need to use encryption/decryption that's why i use CryptoSwift library. Can you please suggest me..?

Comment: Apple provided Common Crypto is fast and correct because is uses the builtin crypto hardware, CryptoSwift does not. In the CryptoSwift ReadMe the rational for it's develop,enmt is "Why? Because I can.", not be cause it is better in some way. Also notice there are no benchmarks other than in in Issues: Speed Questions #30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "CryptoSwift":
```

Please find below error, I saw when try to install pod in your project.

[image]

I found this error while `pod install` in your demo project.

**Solution**

Remove `pod 'CryptoSwift'` from your **podfile**, then do **pod install**

then again add `pod 'CryptoSwift'` in your **podfile** and run **pod install**, it will work.

Your pod file will looks like this,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'CryptoSwiftDemo' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'CryptoSwift'

    # Pods for CryptoSwiftDemo

end
```

Comment: Got it.Thanks for help
What is mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check  swift version of the framework, if it is of older swift version, toggle the "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" from "No" to "Yes" in project settings. Refer [Use Legacy Swift Language Version - Xcode 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118912/use-legacy-swift-language-version-xcode-8-2) for more.

Hope this will help.